# Where can I find the source-code for netlib-java?

Tags: java, linear-algebra, apache-spark-mllib, netlib-java

Spark's MLLib states that https://github.com/fommil/netlib-java is a [dependency](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/mllib-guide.html#dependencies).

However, this repo has been removed from github (**the above link is dead**). Google's cached version of the pages is still there, and there is a note that the library would be discontinued due to lack of funding.

Is the library no longer maintained? Where is the upstream branch now (I can see a few forks in github)? The author, Sam Halliday has moved [most of his projects to GitLab](https://gitlab.com/fommil) but the repo doesn't appear to exist there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the official one here: https://gitlab.com/fommil/attic/tree/master/netlib-java

It's in the `attic` project which reads "Old mothballed projects that I'm not maintaining anymore"

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a reasonably up to date fork [here](https://github.com/oignatenko/netlib-java).